# Search recursive for files that contains a specific combination of strings on the first line

Tags: linux, awk, grep, find, head

I need to find all files that cointains in the first line the strings: "StockID" and "SellPrice".

Here is are some exemples of files :

1.csv :

```
StockID Dept    Cat2    Cat4    Cat5    Cat6    Cat1    Cat3    Title   Notes   Active  Weight  Sizestr Colorstr    Quantity    Newprice    StockCode   DateAdded   SellPrice   PhotoQuant  PhotoStatus Description stockcontrl Agerestricted
<blank> 1   0   0   0   0   22  0   RAF Air Crew Oxygen Connector   50801   1   150 <blank> <blank> 0   0   50866   2018-09-11 05:54:03 65  5   1   <br />\r\nA wartime RAF aircrew oxygen hose connector.<br />\r\n<br />\r\nAir Ministry stamped with Ref. No. 6D/482, Mk IVA.<br />\r\n<br />\r\nBrass spring loaded top bayonet fitting for the 'walk around' oxygen bottle extension hose (see last photo).<br />\r\n<br />\r\nIn a good condition.    2   0
<blank> 1   0   0   0   0   15  0   WW2 US Airforce Type Handheld Microphone    50619   1   300 <blank> <blank> 1   0   50691   2017-12-06 09:02:11 20  9   1   <br />\r\nWW2 US Airforce Handheld Microphone type NAF 213264-6 and sprung mounting Bracket No. 213264-2.<br />\r\n<br />\r\nType RS 38-A.<br />\r\n<br />\r\nMade by Telephonics Corp.<br />\r\n<br />\r\nIn a un-issued condition.    3   0
<blank> 1   0   0   0   0   22  0   RAF Seat Type Parachute Harness <blank> 1   4500    <blank> <blank> 1   0   50367   2016-11-04 12:02:26 155 8   1   <br />\r\nPost War RAF Pilot Seat Type Parachute Harness.<br />\r\n<br />\r\nThis Irvin manufactured harness is 'new old' stock and is unissued.<br />\r\n<br />\r\nThe label states Irvin Harness type C, Mk10, date 1976.<br />\r\nIt has Irvin marked buckles and complete harness straps all in 'mint' condition.<br />\r\n<br />\r\nFully working Irvin Quick Release Box and a canopy release Irvin  'D-Ring' Handle.<br />\r\n<br />\r\nThis harness is the same style type as the WW2 pattern seat type, and with some work could be made to look like one.<br />\r\n<br />\r\nIdeal for the re-enactor or collector (Not sold for parachuting).<br />\r\n<br />\r\nTotal weight of 4500 gms.   3   0
```

2.csv :

```
id  user_id organization_id hash    name    email   date    first_name  hear_about
1   2   15  <blank> Fairley teisjdaijdsaidja@domain.com 1129889679  John    0
```

I only want to find the files that contains on 1st line : "StockID" and "SellPrice" ; 
So in this exemple, i want to output only ./1.csv

I manage to do this, but i`m stuck now ;(

```
where=$(find "./backup -type f)
for x in $where; do
   head -1 $x | grep -w "StockID"
done
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`find`** + **`awk`** solution:

```
find ./backup -type f -exec \
awk 'NR == 1{ if (/StockID.*SellPrice/) print FILENAME; exit }' {} \;
```

In case if the order of crucial words may be different - replace pattern `/StockID.*SellPrice/` with `/StockID/ && /SellPrice/`.

---

In case of huge number of files a more efficient alternative would be (processing a bunch of files at once; the total number of invocations of the command will be much less than the number of matched  files):

```
find ./backup -type f -exec \
awk 'FNR == 1 && /StockID.*SellPrice/{ print FILENAME }{ nextfile }' {} +
```

Comment: i own you a coffee! it works.

Comment: @user000001, see my update

Comment: how about making it more efficient with `awk 'FNR == 1 &&/StockID.*SellPrice/ {print FILENAME}; {nextfile }' {} +`. This will lead to fewer invocations of `awk`

Comment: @iruvar, good hint. I've made an update. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `grep` or compatible:

```
grep -Hrnm1 '^' ./backup | sed -n '/StockID.*SellPrice/s/:1:.*//p'
```

The recursive grep will print the first line of each file and print a `filename:1:line` *without* reading through the whole file (the `-m1` flag should make it exit at the 1st match) and the `sed` will print the `filename` where the `line` part matches the pattern.

This will fail with file *names* which contain a `:1:` themselves or newline characters, but this is a risk worth taking instead of putting up some slow `find` + `awk` combo which executes another process for each file.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid running one command per file and reading the entire files, with GNU `awk`:

```
(unset -v POSIXLY_CORRECT; exec find backup/ -type f -exec gawk '
  /\<StockID\>/ && /\<SellPrice\>/ {print FILENAME}; {nextfile}' {} +)
```

Or with `zsh`:

```
set -o rematchpcre # where we know for sure \b is supported
for file (backup/**/*(ND.)) {
  IFS= read -r line < $file &&
   [[ $line =~ "\bStockID\b" ]] &&
   [[ $line =~ "\bSellPrice\b" ]] &&
   print -r $file
}
```

Or:

```
set -o rematchpcre
print -rl backup/**/*(D.e:'
  IFS= read -r line < $REPLY &&
   [[ $line =~ "\bStockID\b" ]] &&
   [[ $line =~ "\bSellPrice\b" ]]':)
```

Or with `bash` on systems where native extended regular expressions support `\<`, `\>` word boundary operators (on others, you some others, you could also try `[[:<:]]`/`[[:>:]]` or `\b` instead):

```
RE1='\<StockId\>' RE2='\<SellPrice\>' find backup -type f -exec bash -c '
  for file do
    IFS= read -r line < "$file" &&
    [[ $line =~ $RE1 ]] &&
    [[ $line =~ $RE2 ]] &&
    printf "%s\n" "$file"
  done' bash {} +
```

Comment: Stéphane , I'm guessing you're going to have to account for `$0`, so the `done' {} +` should read something like `done' bash {} +` ?

Answer (score 0):

`egrep` + `awk` :

```
 egrep -Hrn 'StockID|SellPrice' ./backup | awk -F ':' '$2==1{print $1}'
```